# finding and matching next address, but want to drop if string is too close

Tags: r

I have a somewhat messy address database that track moves by a given order in long format. I want to add columns to match it to the next address, but I want to skip it / drop the entry if the next address is too close.

The process I have so far mirrors this one:

```
ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
Set = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3)
Street = c("123 Mulburry St", "234 Willow St", "235 Willow St", "492 Basin st", "231 Farrow st", "492 Little st", "231 Big st")

df = data.frame(ID, Set, Street)

df <- df %>% mutate(set_id = paste0(ID,  "_", Set))
df <- df %>% mutate(next_id = paste0(ID,  "_", (Set + 1)))

match <- subset(df, select = c(set_id, Street))
match <- match %>% rename(next_street = Street)

df <- left_join(df, match, by = c("next_id" = "set_id"))
df$problem <- stringdist(df$Street, df$next_street) < 2
```

However, I would want to drop A3, where the set goes from 234 Willow St to 235 Willow St, assuming that this is an error / typo (basically, drop what is flagged in df$problem). But I can't really figure how I would drop that and replace it with the correct line (which, would be from A_2 to A_4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks at the next address and drops it if it is close. It uses `agrepl` which can also be fine tuned with `cost` and `max.distance`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Street2=lag(Street)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Street=ifelse(agrepl(Street, Street2)==T,NA,Street), Street2=NULL) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  ID      Set Street         
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>          
1 A         1 123 Mulburry St
2 A         2 234 Willow St  
3 A         3 NA             
4 A         4 492 Basin st   
5 B         1 231 Farrow st  
6 B         2 492 Little st  
7 B         3 231 Big st
```

Comment: Oh, this looks promising! How do you set the tolerance using agrepl? I'm a little confused on how its operating still. Thanks!

Comment: @tchoup It can be fine tuned using `cost`, which is the maximum number/fraction of match cost (generalized Levenshtein distance) or with `max.distance`, which is the maximum distance allowed for a match. It can be set as `insertions`, `deletions` and `substitutions`, or all in one with `all` (integer number or fraction).

Comment: @tchoup generally not needed though, just for fringe cases.